# mysql select outputing 2 lines: with and without substring

Tags: mysql, select, newline

I'm doing a mysql select statement that outputs the first 5 letters of a `field1` using substring.

```
select substring(field1,1,5) from table1 //query with substring
```

I'd like to output not only the substring, but also the original, but I'd like them on 2 separate lines. I'm guessing a `concat` with `NEWLINE` could do the job, but not sure what's the new line character in mysql.

This is what I have in mind:

```
select concat(field1, NEWLINE, substring(field1,1,5)) from table1
```

**Edit:**
I'm working on windows, so "\n" doesn't work. '\r' works, but only if I open the file in Notepad++. In normal notepad, it shows the 2 strings as 1 connected line. I realize there's a carriage return in there, but I'd like to see it in Notepad without having to open Notepad++. So is there a platform independent NEWLINE? something like EOL in php that figures out the appropriate new line for that specific platform.

Answer (score 0):

Juse use "\n" instead of NEWLINE.

Comment: I'm working on windows, so `"\n"` doesn't work. `'\r'` works, but only if I open the file in Notepad++. In normal notepad, it shows the 2 strings as 1 connected line. I realize there's a carriage return in there, but I'd like to see it in Notepad without having to open Notepad++. So is there a platform independent NEWLINE? something like `EOL` in php that figures out the appropriate new line for that specific platform.

Answer (score 0):

Replace NEWLINE with '\r\n'. It is the windows line separator.

```
select concat(field1, '\r\n', substring(field1,1,5))
from table1
```